# How to get access to Firebase realtime database from two different activities?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project in which I have created a custom java class in which I have made a firebase database instance so, that when I need access to the database I could make a instance of my custom class and have access to the database and when I call the database through my custom java object in activity "A" it works properly but when I call the database in activity "B" then the activity "B" gets suddenly crashed. How can I resolve this issue?

Custom java class code

```
public class databaseApp  {
        public databaseApp() {
        }
    
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef =  database.getReference();
        String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        
    
        public void writeNewUser(String u, String e, String p, String tcn){
    
    
            user user = new user();
            user.setUserName(u);
            user.setEmail(e);
            user.setPhone(p);
            user.setTcn(tcn);
            myRef.child("User").child(getUniqueId()).child("User Data").setValue(user);
           
    
        }
        public void addBatchToDatabase(String batchName,String startDate,String endDate,String fees, String startTiming,String endTiming){
            addBatchDatabase addbatchDetails = new addBatchDatabase();
            addbatchDetails.setBatchName(batchName);
            addbatchDetails.setStartDate(startDate);
            addbatchDetails.setEndDate(endDate);
            addbatchDetails.setFees(fees);
            addbatchDetails.setStartTimimg(startTiming);
            addbatchDetails.setEndTimimg(endTiming);
                   DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference(id);
            myref.push().child("Batch").setValue(addbatchDetails);
        }
```

Activity "A" code

```
databaseApp databaseApp = new databaseApp();
databaseApp.writeNewUser(N.getText().toString(),E.getText().toString(),P.getText().toString(),tcn.getText().toString());
```

Activity "B" code

```
databaseApp databaseApp = new databaseApp();
databaseApp.addBatchToDatabase(batchName.getText().toString(),startDate.getText().toString(),endDate.getText().toString(),fees.getText().toString(),startTime.getText().toString(),endTime.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Which exception that you do not catch lets your app crash? Look in the logcat.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo